# config iptables rules for pptp vpn

Tags: iptables, vpn, firewall, centos6

I used [Setup PPTP VPN Server on CentOS 6](https://www.vultr.com/docs/setup-pptp-vpn-server-on-centos-6) guid to setup pptp vpn on my server.

Every things is fine and vpn work without csf and iptables.

But when i enable csf / iptables i can't connect to  vpn server.

I need this config to iptables:

`iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -s 192.168.81.0/24 -j MASQUERADE`

And this lines exist in my iptables, but doesn't work!

Here is my iptables config

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sun Aug  5 00:50:28 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [24:1570]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [5:300]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:404]
-A PREROUTING -s 157.97.106.169/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m multiport --dports 443,4041,4041 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8887 
-A PREROUTING -s 157.97.106.169/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m multiport --dports 4041,80,4041,2222 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8888 
-A PREROUTING -s 157.97.106.169/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8889 
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.81.0/24 -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE 
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.81.0/24 -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug  5 00:50:28 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sun Aug  5 00:50:28 2018
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [13570:36806740]
:INPUT ACCEPT [13428:36795380]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13349:37566165]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [13324:37563017]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug  5 00:50:28 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sun Aug  5 00:50:28 2018
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [13570:36806740]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [13349:37566165]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug  5 00:50:28 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sun Aug  5 00:50:28 2018
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
:ALLOWIN - [0:0]
:ALLOWOUT - [0:0]
:DENYIN - [0:0]
:DENYOUT - [0:0]
:INVALID - [0:0]
:INVDROP - [0:0]
:LOCALINPUT - [0:0]
:LOCALOUTPUT - [0:0]
:LOGDROPIN - [0:0]
:LOGDROPOUT - [0:0]
:SMTPOUTPUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8889 -m limit --limit 100/sec --limit-burst 150 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8888 -m limit --limit 100/sec --limit-burst 150 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8887 -m limit --limit 100/sec --limit-burst 150 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 213.186.33.99/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 213.186.33.99/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 213.186.33.99/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s 213.186.33.99/32 ! -i lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -j LOCALINPUT 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -j INVALID 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m limit --limit 1/sec -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j LOGDROPIN 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 3031 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 143 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 4041 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 35000:35999 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT ! -i lo -j LOGDROPIN 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8889 -m limit --limit 100/sec --limit-burst 150 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8888 -m limit --limit 100/sec --limit-burst 150 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 8887 -m limit --limit 100/sec --limit-burst 150 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 213.186.33.99/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 213.186.33.99/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 213.186.33.99/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -d 213.186.33.99/32 ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -j LOCALOUTPUT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -j SMTPOUTPUT 
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -j INVALID 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p icmp -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 3031 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 110 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 587 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 995 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 4041 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 8888 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m tcp --dport 8889 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 113 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT ! -o lo -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 69.162.69.58/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 66.51.122.131/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 192.169.82.155/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 2.180.20.174/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 46.209.31.61/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 185.23.129.202/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 178.236.40.179/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 37.59.211.45/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWIN -s 2.180.20.174/32 ! -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 69.162.69.58/32 ! -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 66.51.122.131/32 ! -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 192.169.82.155/32 ! -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 2.180.20.174/32 ! -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 46.209.31.61/32 ! -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 185.23.129.202/32 ! -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 178.236.40.179/32 ! -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 37.59.211.45/32 ! -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A ALLOWOUT -d 2.180.20.174/32 ! -o lo -j ACCEPT 
-A DENYIN -s 157.97.106.169/32 ! -i lo -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 191.96.249.114/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 191.96.249.114/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 191.96.249.114/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 191.96.249.122/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 191.96.249.122/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 191.96.249.122/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 191.96.249.135/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 191.96.249.135/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 191.96.249.135/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 37.187.119.2/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 37.187.119.2/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 37.187.119.2/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 145.249.105.210/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 145.249.105.210/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 145.249.105.210/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 145.249.107.135/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 145.249.107.135/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 145.249.107.135/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 145.249.104.245/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 145.249.104.245/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j DROP 
-A DENYIN -s 145.249.104.245/32 ! -i lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j DROP 
-A DENYOUT -d 157.97.106.169/32 ! -o lo -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 191.96.249.114/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 191.96.249.114/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 191.96.249.114/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 191.96.249.122/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 191.96.249.122/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 191.96.249.122/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 191.96.249.135/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 191.96.249.135/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 191.96.249.135/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 37.187.119.2/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 37.187.119.2/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 37.187.119.2/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 145.249.105.210/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 145.249.105.210/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 145.249.105.210/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 145.249.107.135/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 145.249.107.135/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 145.249.107.135/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 145.249.104.245/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 145.249.104.245/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 465 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A DENYOUT -d 145.249.104.245/32 ! -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 587 -j LOGDROPOUT 
-A INVALID -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN FIN,SYN -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN,RST -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,RST FIN,RST -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,ACK FIN -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags PSH,ACK PSH -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags ACK,URG URG -j INVDROP 
-A INVALID -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j INVDROP 
-A INVDROP -j DROP 
-A LOCALINPUT ! -i lo -j ALLOWIN 
-A LOCALINPUT ! -i lo -j DENYIN 
-A LOCALOUTPUT ! -o lo -j ALLOWOUT 
-A LOCALOUTPUT ! -o lo -j DENYOUT 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 23 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 23 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 111 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 111 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 113 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 113 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 135:139 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 135:139 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 445 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 500 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 513 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 513 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m tcp --dport 520 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m udp --dport 520 -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPIN -p tcp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_IN Blocked* " 
-A LOGDROPIN -j DROP 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *TCP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p udp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *UDP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -p icmp -m limit --limit 30/min -j LOG --log-prefix "Firewall: *ICMP_OUT Blocked* " --log-uid 
-A LOGDROPOUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
-A SMTPOUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -j ACCEPT 
-A SMTPOUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --gid-owner mail -j ACCEPT 
-A SMTPOUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -m owner --uid-owner root -j ACCEPT 
-A SMTPOUTPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 25,465,587 -j LOGDROPOUT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Aug  5 00:50:28 2018
```

Comment: If you used CSF then you have to allow that port 1723 in CSF. You also should be aware that PPTP is not secure and will not protect you from surveillance by your Internet service provider or government.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thank you for answer. The port 1723 is allowed in csf but it doesn't work And which VPN is secure?

Comment: Probably the best one to use is OpenVPN. It is easier to set up than IPSec (which would also be secure, if you use IKEv2 keying).

Comment: Note that for PPTP you also need to allow the GRE protocol i.e. something like `iptables -A INPUT -p 47 -j ACCEPT`. Same for OUTPUT probably.